# Retreiving specific letters from Text in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I have the column as you can see in this image.

[image: Distributor Address]

The Distributor Address is in the format: "**Street Address, Postcode, State**".

I need to retrieve only "**Postcode**" and "**State**" and combine them.

The new column should be like this ➡"**NSW2007**","**VIC3182**"...

How could I retrieve the specific letters and combine them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several ways of solving that. I will show a solution using a few basic functions: **RIGHT**, **MID** and **LEN**.

Assuming your data is on A1:

```
=RIGHT(A1,3)&MID(A1, LEN(A1)-8, 4)
```

*RIGHT returns the 3 last characters from the cell A1.*

*MID returns the middle of the cell given a starting position and a length.*

*LEN gives you the starting position of the zip code, which is always the length of the string - 8 in your table.*

Is it essential that your data is well organized as in the image to work well. One alternative is finding the ", " as below.

```
=RIGHT(A1,3)&MID(A1, FIND(", ",A1)+2,4)
```

Comment: Did you follow my answer?

Comment: I submitted mine before seeing yours, when I started to write your answer was not on the page yet. But yes, I got your answer, it's a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FILTERXML` if you have the newest version of Excel. See [Excel - Extract substring(s) from string using FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml) for an excellent overview.

In this case, something like the below should work:

EDIT: overlooked the specific format you wanted

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[3]")&
FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[2]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a different way:

```
=RIGHT(A2,3)&","&TRIM(MID(A2,FIND(",",A2,1)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND(",",A2,FIND(",",A2,1)+1)))
```

[image]

This does rely on the state being the last 3 characters and the postcode after the first comma...